# oracle sqlcl and sqlplus - seperate login.sql on linux

Tags: oracle, linux, sqlplus, oracle-sqlcl

I feel I'm probably missing something obvious here, but I can't see an easy way to have a separate login.sql for sqlplus and sqlcl

This is problematic for me as the errors thrown up by sqlplus for the `set` commands it doesn't understand interfere with various scripts.

I think I could do it with aliases that change the SQLPATH prior to starting sqlcl, but would prefer a cleaner way if possible.

Is there a separate file name that only sqlcl will look for? Or separate location?